# Linear regression of line in 3-dimensions

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

I am trying to regress a *line* (not a surface) in 3-dimensions and having a total brain freeze for how to do this.

What I have is a data set that (I think) defines a line in 3-dimensions. So in my mind I need to regress $z(x, y) = ax + by +c$, but where x and y are also functions of each other so that a line is defined i.e. as *x* varies then *y* must also vary, they can't vary independently as in a surface. (Plus I have a categorical variable). So it's a multiple regression, but not, if that makes any sense?

In R I've tried `lm(z ~ x * y * categorical)` but this gives me a regressed surface, which is not what I want.

I guess I have to be able to define *x* as a function of *y* in the model (or vice-versa) but I can't work out how to do this from the equation of a line in 3-d. I'm probably being really dumb, sorry.

Comment: Let's call the parameter $t$ which varies inside $x$ and $y$, so that $x$ is a function $f_{x}(t)$ and $y$ is a function $f_{y}(t)$. Do you already know the functional form for $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$? Must it be a straight line?

Comment: Hello. Yes it needs to be a straight line. I've just had a revelation though and realised that PCA will effectively do this for me...

Comment: PCA may approximate a result, but it is not regression.  Regression is what you would do with a dataset of $(t,x,y)$ values and you view $(x,y)$ as depending linearly on $t$ with some error included.  You appear to be thinking of a subtly different situation in which you have $(x,y,z)$ values and a "hidden" variable $t$ for which $(x,y,z)$ depends linearly on $t$ plus some random error.  That indeed can be solved by PCA (although, of course, you cannot determine how $(x,y,z)$ depends on $t$).

Comment: Indeed. But if I “just” want to fit a line and make some reasonable predictions then instead of doing a regression I could do PCA and then use the direction of the first principle component as my line of best fit. I guess that’s closer (the same?) as orthogonal regression than ordinary least squares, where all the error is assumed to be in the dependent variable? Of course if you are able to provide a more traditional regression approach, then I would welcome it as an answer.